# Recursive query using postgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

My dataBase contains data (Image for example) and this data can be modified by a program (Image processing for example) so I get a new image derived from the other, and this image could be modified as well, etc...

2 Images could also be used to create a new one, for example: image a + image b = image c

So in my dataBase I have a table call "Derived from" which contains 2 columns (previous_id, new_id), previous_id is the image before an image processing and new_id is the result. So I can have a "change history" like this:

```
+------------------+------------------+
| id_previous      | id_new           |
+------------------+------------------+
| a                | c                |
| b                | c                |
| c                | d                |
| d                | e                |
+------------------+------------------+
```

So my questions is:

Is it possible to make a recursive query to have all the history of an data ID ?

Something like this:

```
Select * from derived_from where id_new = 'e'
```

Should return (d,c,b,a)

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can achieve this with a [recursive CTE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html):

```
with recursive r as (
    select id_previous
    from   derived_from
    where  id_new = 'e'
  union
    select d.id_previous
    from   derived_from d
    join   r on id_new = r.id_previous
)
select id_previous
from   r
```

http://rextester.com/NZKT73800

*Notes*:

- `UNION` can stop the recursion even when you have loops. With `UNION ALL`, you should handle loops yourself, unless you are **really** sure you have no loops.
- This will give you separate rows (one for each "ascendant"). You can aggregate this too, but it's typically much more easier to consume than comma separated lists or arrays.

Comment: It's working, thank you for your help and your indications. It really helped me !

Answer (score 1):

You can use a recursive CTE:

```
with recursive cte as (
      select df.id_new, df.id_previous as parent
      from derived_from df
      where df.id_new = 'e'
      union all
      select cte.id_new, df.id_previous
      from cte join
           derived_from df
           on cte.parent = df.id_new
     )
select id_new, array_agg(parent)
from cte
group by id_new;
```